# How do I launch a .jar file with desktop shortcut (targeting a specific jre)

Tags: java, windows, wix, shortcut

I'm trying to create a desktop shortcut that will launch our .jar file.  The current WIX build file below gives the error:

```
 [exec] installMsgs.wxs
 [exec] C:\Users\ME\GIT_REPOS\APP\installer\installApp.wxs(43) :
          error CNDL0035 : The Shortcut/@Target attribute cannot be specified when attribute Advertise is present with value 'yes'.
 [exec] C:\Users\ME\GIT_REPOS\APP\installer\installApp.wxs(43) :
          error CNDL0062 : The Shortcut/@Target attribute cannot be specified
```

when the Shortcut element is nested underneath a File element.

But according to this: http://goo.gl/yoSTz it should work. I've tried creating a shortcut outside of he file element as its own component for the javaw.exe file but that didn't work either.  Thanks for any help.

Here is the section from my build file:

```
<Directory Id='D_MyApp' Name='MyApp'>
                        <Component Id='c_myApp' Guid='4f909d90-e31c-44ce-a0af-7042f226611b'>
                            <File Id='myApp' Name='MyApp.jar'
                                Source='..\MyApp\target\Myapp.jar' KeyPath='yes'>
                                <Shortcut Id="s_myApp" Directory="DesktopFolder"
                                    Target="[INSTALLDIR]\jre6\bin\java.exe" 
                                    Arguments="-jar MyApp.jar"
                                    Name="My App" 
                                    WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                                    Icon="MyApp.exe"
                                    Advertise="yes" />
                            </File>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                    <Directory Id='D_jre' Name='jre6'>
                        <Directory Id='D_lib' Name='lib'>
                            <Directory Id='D_ext' Name='ext'>
                                <Component Id='c_SerialIOjars' Guid='a4bc45fe-b62f-478e-ab57-ca5e3e16b42d'>
                                    <File Id='f_jspComm.jar' Name='jspComm.jar'
                                        Source='..\RadioServer\lib\SerialIO\jspComm.jar' KeyPath='no'>
                                    </File>
                                    <File Id='f_Serialio.jar' Name='Serialio.jar'
                                        Source='..\RadioServer\lib\SerialIO\Serialio.jar' KeyPath='no'>
                                    </File>
                                </Component>
                            </Directory>
                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
```

Comment: Have you considered deploying the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?  JWS not only can ensure a specific JRE version, but can install desktop shortcuts and menu items to launch the app. on supported OS' ranging across Windows, OS X & *nix.

Comment: The application is going to be installed on a closed system with no access to the outside internet so that wont work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

I currently just created a .bat file that launches the jar by targeting the JRE javaw.exe file we include and have a shorcut to the .bat file on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I currently just created a .bat file that launches the jar by targeting the JRE javaw.exe file we include and have a shorcut to the .bat file on the desktop. Easiest way to get the result I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because when `Shortcut` element is nested inside `File`, its `Target` is assumed to be the file itself.

It's not what you want, therefore `Shortcut` element should be side-by-side with `MyApp.jar` or in another component. Plus you'd really like to use the full path to `MyApp.jar` when you pass it as argument to JRE.